# Trying to call a flask function with parameters from html

Tags: python, html, flask

So Im calling a flask function which takes one parameter check from my html code, im getting the error: TypeError: categories_html() missing 1 required positional argument: 'check'.

Heres my Python code:

```
app.route('/cat_html', methods=['GET'])
def categories_html(check):
    if session.get('teacher_name'):
        return trav0.gen(check)

    else:
        return redirect('/teachers')
```

And then here is the html call:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('categories_html', check='sta10') }}" target="_blank" style="color:31708f;">Tasks</a>
</li>
```

So trav0.gen generates a html, check is simply equal to a number, depending on the number a different html is generated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you want the url to look like for `cat_html`.

You can do a couple things.

For a url like `/cat_html/sta10` you would write the method like:

```
@app.route('/cat_html/<check>', methods=['GET'])
def categories_html(check):
    # use check here
    return check
```

`check` will be part of the url path.

To pass check as a query parameter with a url like  `/cat_html/?check=sta10`, you don't add it as parameter to the function, you `get()` it in the function:

```
@app.route('/cat_html/', methods=['GET'])
def categories_html():
    check = request.args.get('check', '')
    # use check here
    return check
```